# CleanCommand parameters are missing

Tags: c#, git, jgit, ngit

Using NGit I need to run **git clean** command equivalent to the following CLI command:

```
git clean -f -d
```

But there are no such options as force or clean directories in [CleanCommand class](https://github.com/mono/ngit/blob/master/NGit/NGit.Api/CleanCommand.cs). What's the best workaround here?

Answer (score 0):

JGit (on which NGit is based) supports `-d`, see the [API documentation](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CleanCommand.html#setCleanDirectories%28boolean%29).

So it seems the best solution would be if NGit updated to the newest JGit release, I'd file a bug for that.

As for a workaround, maybe it is possible to implement this yourself, see the [Java implementation of CleanCommand](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/tree/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CleanCommand.java#n92) (if NGit provides the necessary lower-level API for this).